# XSLT - calculating sum of price for chosen nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I' ve got following xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<audioteka xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="audioteka.xsd">

<CD id="p1">
<title>Butchered at Birth</title>
<author>Cannibal Corpse</author>
<genre>Metal</genre>
<release_date>1991-06-30</release_date>
<price currency="PLN">49.99</price>
<publisher>
    <name>Napalm Records</name>
    <country>USA</country>
</publisher>
</CD>
<CD id = "p2">
<title>Battalions of Fear</title>
<author>Blind Guardian</author>
<genre>Metal</genre>
<release_date>1988-02-15</release_date>
<price currency="PLN">34.99</price>
<publisher>
    <name>BMG</name>
    <country>Belgia</country>
</publisher>
</CD>
<CD id = "p3">
<title>Dangerous Days</title>
<author>Perturbator</author>
<genre>Synthwave</genre>
<release_date>2014-09-17</release_date>
<price currency="EUR">52.99</price>
<publisher>
    <name>Mystic Productions</name>
    <country>Polska</country>
</publisher>
</CD>
</audioteka>
```

And this code for xml transformation using xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
version="1.0"
xmlns:a="http://www.test.com/">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="Num" select="2"/>

<xsl:template match="audioteka">
     Zamowienie - faktura       
<xsl:for-each select="/audioteka/CD">
    <xsl:sort select="author" order="descending" />
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= $Num">
    Tytul: <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    Autor: <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
    Gatunek: <xsl:value-of select="genre"/>
    Cena: <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
    ----------------------------------
    </xsl:if>     
</xsl:for-each>
```

But i don't have any idea how to calculate sum of titles and prices for 5 selected CDs. I tried using

```
Suma: <xsl:value-of select="sum(@price)"/>
```

but this gives me wrong values. Did anyone have idea for solution?

Comment: `price` is an element and not an attribute. So you can try `Suma: <xsl:value-of select="sum(CD/price)"/>`. But this only returns the sum of all `price`s and not only the selected ones.

Comment: What exactly does "selected" mean here? Who does the selecting and how is it passed to the transformation?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I want to make a invoice.  In my xml code i have 15 different CDS. In XSLT transformation i want choose few of them by using param Num and calculate sum of prices and titles. I want to make a invoice.

Comment: How exactly should the param `Num` be used to make a selection? I only see a single number. If you want to select 5 CDs, I would expect a list of 5 unique `id` values.

Comment: I used like this <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= $Num">. Earlier i have problem with it, but i found solution on one of web pages. I check results here and it works: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/#.XC963lVKjIU

Comment: And if I use this list, it will be easier to sum values?

Comment: That is a strange way to select, because it only allows you to select the first N nodes, never any others. Anyway, should this test: `position() &lt;= $Num` be applied to the nodes **before** you sort them, or **after**? That will make a big difference. -- No, it will not make it easier or more difficult. I am just trying to understand what exactly are you trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0):

The idea to solve the issue is:

- Store required elements in a variable.
- Run the `for-each` loop drawing the content from this variable.
- Sum prices also from this variable.

A bit of complication is that in XSLT 1.0 the type of this variable
is *Result Tree Fragment (RTF)*, so it can not be directly used in *XPath*
expressions.

To circumvent this limitation, you must use `exsl:node-set` function,
converting such *RTF* to *node set* and then use it in *XPath*.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:param name="Num" select="2"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="discs">
      <xsl:for-each select="audioteka/CD">
        <xsl:sort select="author" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= $Num">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:text>Zamowienie - faktura&#x0A;&#x0A;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($discs)/CD">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Tytul:   ', title, '&#x0A;')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Autor:   ', author, '&#x0A;')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Gatunek: ', genre, '&#x0A;')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Cena:    ', price, '&#x0A;')"/>
      <xsl:text>----------------------------------&#x0A;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Suma:    ', sum($discs/CD/price),
      '&#x0A;')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see, I also made some corrections concerning output generation.

The first thing to notice is output method = *text*, because you generate
"ordinary" text, not an XML.

Another change is that for text output I use `xsl:text` and `&#x0A;` for newlines.
The advantage is that the code (and text) indentation in the script does not
influence output indentation.

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/3MP2uBx